# Disabling Java JIT at runtime

Tags: java, jit, jvm-hotspot

Is there a way/API to disable (or tune) the java JIT during execution, of a java program.

My use case is a code that is executed a large number of times, and after some time (let's say 10 seconds), I want to prevent the JIT from running, as we're seeing latency spikes related to JIT (from traces) on that specific code (or any code in the program if it's the only way).

I know one can disable it at start-up but I'm more looking for a way to interact with it at runtime : still getting the performance on already JITed code, but preventing further execution of the JIT compiler.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can only disable it at startup, not at runtime.

Comment: You could perhaps try to tune the `-XX:CompileThreshold` option to see if you can get it to compile your code earlier (or later).

Comment: What is OS/JVM version? It's possible to disable JIT in runtime, but this seems to me an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). JIT compiler threads are running in background. How do you see they affect latency?

Comment: Hi, @apangin I see the difference in running times over very long period of times, where whenever the JIT spouts a trace, I see some latency jitter in the specific code. Disabling at start-up makes the execution time perfectly constant (but awfully slow) even on very long period of times. The threads are shielded with cpuset+isolcpus, I've tried many things before focusing on JIT, and the latency spikes seem really correlated with JIT passes.

Comment: @Hulk I tried different values, but it seems that in any case it recompiles some part or others of the application, and it's very finnicky to tune (for every code modification I had to retune).

Comment: Correlation does not yet mean that disabling JIT will help. If the latency spike is caused by deoptimization (quite likely), then it will still happen even with JIT disabled in runtime, with the only difference that the program will become "awfully slow" after deoptimization, like when JIT is disabled from the very beginning.

Comment: So yes, this is an XY problem - I'd suggest you ask about your *original* problem (e.g. how to detect the actual reason of a latency spike), rather than a hypothetical solution which won't probably help.

Comment: I appreciate the advice about XY problems, but: I'm saying the latency spike is happening not in my code but because the JIT *compiler* starts spuriously and interrupts my code. The code in question is not deoptimized, it is just in competition for the same resource as the JIT compiler. I'd like to disable it after my code is optimized (after it was JITed). Detailed perf recording (with probes) and analysis, all say 'your code has been interrupted by the JIT'. I'm just looking for an answer to the specific question? Please?

Comment: If the JIT triggers, doesn't it mean that some new code has become hot and needs to be compiled?
I suppose by "interrupted by the JIT" you mean that the JIT is stealing some CPU time that would otherwise be used by your application?
Does the system stabilize after some reasonable time (i.e., no more "JIT compilation spikes")?